# If you cast Sunbeam, do you get the first beam in the same round you cast the spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, action-economy

I have a question concerning the spell *Sunbeam* (PHB, 289). In the spell description it says:

> For the duration of this spell, you can use a standard action to evoke a dazzling beam of intense light each round.

I´m not sure if this means that you may get the first beam in the same round you cast the spell or whether you have to spend one standard action just casting and then wait for your next round to send forth the first beam?

"Wasting" one standard action just for casting would be a high cost, so I guess you should be able to get the first beam in the round you cast the spell - but it does not say so in the spell description.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unfortunately you do not get a free beam.

As it says, you have to spend a standard action to create the beam.

In [5e Sunbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam) was changed so that 1 beam is fired when you cast the spell:

> A beam of brilliant light flashes out from your hand
>
> ...
>
> You can create a new line of radiance as your action on any turn until the spell ends.

No luck for 3.5e though.

Comment: Unless he will get some of the crazy 3.5 ways to get more action per turns. In such case, he would be able to create a ray on the same turn, using extra action. [Interesting discussion here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?133628-3-5-Extra-Actions).

Comment: @Mołot Absolutely, if you have more actions then you can spend them.